# Dynamic topic in kafka channel using flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng, apache-kafka

Is it possible to have a kafka channel with a dynamic topic - something like the kafka sink where you can specify the topic header, or the HDFS sink where you can use a value from a header?

I know I can multiplex to use multiple channels (with a bunch of channel configurations), but that is undesirable because I'd like to have a single dynamic HDFS sink, rather than an HDFS sink for each kafka channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the Flume Kafka channel can only be mapped to a single topic because it is both producing and consuming logs on that particular topic.

Looking at the code in KafkaChannel.java from Flume 1.6.0, I can see that only one topic is ever subscribed to (with one consumer per thread).